# Statistics find E(x), the number of distinct elements in uniformly distributed pool of items

Tags: probability, statistics, uniform-distribution

Question:

Suppose there are **Y** types of balls in a bucket, which are normally distributed and independent. Hence the probability of picking **one type** out is $\frac{1}{Y}$. Let $x$ be the number of **different** balls taken.
What would the $E(x)$ and $Var(x)$ be?

For example, say there are 5 types of balls, $A,B,C,D$ and $E$. We take out $4$ balls = $ACCD$. Then $x = 3$ types of balls.

Comment: "which are normally distributed" does not make much sense here. Maybe this question asks about the Coupon Collector's Problem (please see Wikipedia). But maybe not.

Comment: Well.. That's the question I am given :/

Comment: The "number of types" is discrete (literally a count); it cannot possibly be normally distributed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take the question to mean: We have $Y$ balls in a bucket and we sample $k$ balls with replacement; what is the expected value of the number $x$ of different balls sampled? (I assume that "are normally distributed and independent", which doesn't seem to make any sense here, is meant to express that the samples are independent and each sample has uniform distribution over the balls; this has nothing to do with a [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution).)

The probability of a single ball being sampled is $1-\left(1-\frac1Y\right)^k$, so the expected number $E[x]$ of balls sampled is $Y\left(1-\left(1-\frac1Y\right)^k\right)$. Denoting by $x_i$ the indicator variable that takes the value $1$ if the $i$-th ball is sampled and $0$ if it isn't, we have $x=\sum x_i$ and thus

$$
E\left[x^2\right]=E\left[\left(\sum_ix_i\right)^2\right]=E\left[Yx_1^2+Y(Y-1)x_1x_2\right]=E[x]+Y(Y-1)E[x_1x_2]^\;.
$$

We can get $E[x_1x_2]$, the probability that two particular balls were sampled, by inclusion-exclusion: $E[x_1x_2]=1-\left(1-\frac1Y\right)^k-\left(1-\frac1Y\right)^k+\left(1-\frac2Y\right)^k$. So the variance is

\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}[x]&=E[x^2]-E[x]^2\\
&=Y(Y-1)\left(1-\left(1-\frac1Y\right)^k-\left(1-\frac1Y\right)^k+\left(1-\frac2Y\right)^k\right)+Y\left(1-\left(1-\frac1Y\right)^k\right)\\
&\quad\quad-Y^2\left(1-\left(1-\frac1Y\right)^k\right)^2\;.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you!
Could you just explain how did you get the E(x)?

Comment: @HC1994: Since $x=\sum x_i$, by [linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity) $E[x]=\sum E\left[x_i\right]$, and each $E[x_i]$ is simply the probability that a particular ball is sampled.

Comment: Sorry about the necromancy. I found that by plugging in some numbers the result for $\operatorname{Var}[x]$ was quite surprising. Isn't there a mistake in the expression for $E[x_1x_2]$? I used a different approach:
$E[x_1 \cap x_2] = \Pr(x_1 \cap x_2) = \Pr(x_1)+\Pr(x_2)-\Pr(x_1 \cup x_2) = \Pr(x_1)+\Pr(x_2)-1+\Pr(\bar{x_1} \cap \bar{x_2}) = \Pr(x_1)+\Pr(x_2)-1+\Pr(\bar{x_1})\Pr(\bar{x_2} \mid \bar{x_1})$
That last expression $\Pr(\bar{x_2} \mid \bar{x_1})$ is I think just $(1-\frac 1 {Y-1})^k$.
This results in numbers more consistent with intuition and experiments. Does it make sense?

Comment: @doc: You called me, master? I think your result is exaxtly the same as mine. (You're using $x_1$ and $x_2$ both for the indicator variables and for the corresponding events, but it nevertheless seems clear enough what you mean.) With $\mathsf{Pr}(x_1)=\mathsf{Pr}(x_2)=1-\left(1-\frac1Y\right)^k$ and $\mathsf{Pr}(\overline{x_1})=\left(1-\frac1Y\right)^k$, I get

$$
E[x_1x_2]=2\left(1-\left(1-\frac1Y\right)^k\right)-1+\left(1-\frac1Y\right)^k\left(1-\frac1{Y-1}\right)^k=1-2\left(1-\frac1Y\right)^k+\left(1-\frac2Y\right)^k\;,
$$

in agreement with my result. Now back to the grave...

Comment: Ah yes, indeed. Nice. Thanks for the prompt and correct answer.
But I went back (because the numbers did not make sense) and I think I found it:
The mistake is in $E\left[Yx_1^2+...\right]=YE[x]+...$: it should be $E[x]$, not $YE[x]$. In turns the second term in $\operatorname{Var[x]}$ should be $Y\left(1-\left(1 - \frac 1 Y\right)^k\right)$.

Comment: @doc: You're right, thanks; I fixed it.

Comment: It was relevant to my application, so I thought I'd just add it here. When $k, Y$ are large, the (somewhat ghastly) expression for $\operatorname{Var}[x]$ can be nicely approximated by $Y(1-u)u$, where $u = \exp(-k/Y)$. We also have $E[x] = Y(1-u)$, and thus $\operatorname{Var}[x] = E[x] u$.