# Finding variance of number of distinct values chosen from a set with replacement

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

There are k unique values, and we choose n of them with replacement. Let x be the number of unique values chosen, independently and uniformly.

I found the expected value:

$$\begin{align}E[X] &= k(1-(1-\frac1k)^{n}).\end{align}$$

I got a very long and complicated answer for variance, using covariance, that I think is wrong.

How would I find Var[$X$]?

Comment: Your answer for mean and variance should depend on $k$ as well.

Comment: The posted $E(Y)$ is not right. What was the basic tool you used? Indicator random variables?

Comment: @AndréNicolas my bad, I edited the post. Yes I used indicator variables.

Comment: Then continue to use indicator variables to compute $E(X^2)$, the idea is exactly the same, only now one deals with products of two indicator variables.

Comment: You can use `\left` and `\right` before opening and closing parentheses, respectively, (and before any other pair of delimiters) to let the size of the parentheses automatically adjust to their contents.

Comment: I'm not closing this as a duplicate because the other question is very confusingly posed, but the intended meaning is the same and it has an accepted answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1464588.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used indicators to do:
$$\begin{align}
\mathsf E[X] & = \sum_{j=1}^k \mathsf P[X_j{=}1] \\ & = \sum_{j=1}^k (1-\mathsf P[X_j{=}0]) \\ & = k (1-(1-\frac{1}{k})^n)\end{align}$$

So continue:
$$\begin{align}\mathsf E[X^2]
 & = \sum_{j=1}^k \mathsf P[X_j{=}1] + \mathop{\sum\sum}_{\substack{j\in\{1;k\}\\i\in\{1;n\}\setminus\{j\}}}\mathsf P[X_j{=}1,X_i{=}1] \\ & = \ldots
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Comments:

(1) I suppose you may already know that this is closely related to
the famous birthday problem.

(2) If $n$ is moderately large compared with very large $k,$
then $Y = n - X$ (the number of redundancies) may be approximately Poisson.

(3) If $k = 20$ and $n = 10,$ then your formula has $E(X) = 8.0253$.
A simulation of a million such experiments gives
$E(X) \approx 8.025$ and $SD(X) \approx 1.037.$ The latter
number may be useful to you in checking the result you get
following @GrahamKemp's lead.

The R code follows, in case you are not allergic to computation
for visualization on the way to an analytic solution.

```
 m = 10^6;  k = 20;  n = 10;  x = numeric(m)
 for (i in 1:m) {
    draw = sample(1:k, n, rep=T)
    x[i] = length(unique(draw)) }
 mean(x);  sd(x)
 ## 8.024469
 ## 1.037192
```

[image]

As an example of (2), if $k = 400$ and $n = 20,$ then simulation
shows that $Y$ is
approximately $Poisson(0.47).$ In the figure below the histogram
shows the simulated distribution of $Y$ and the blue dots show
this Poisson distribution.
[image]